# Can I use malloc when defining a structure?

Tags: c

Is there any way to dynamically allocate memory for a structure in the definition of the structure, and if it can't be done, what is the best way to dynamically allocate memory for that structure ?

```
typedef struct user_t{
    char user_name[30];
    char email[50];
    int movieswatched;
    movie *movielist;
}user_t;
```

I want to allocate memory for movielist .

Comment: Edited , now you can see what im trying to do

Comment: You can’t do that with the C programming language

Comment: I appreciate your question is tagged 'C' not 'C++', but this is exactly the sort of thing constructors are used for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it in the definition of the structure (which wouldn't make much sense anyway as you don't yet know the number of movies and because different `user_t` variables might have different number of movies).

You need to do it at runtime, for example like this:

```
user_t v;
...
v.movielist = malloc(sizeof(movie) * numberofmovies);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
typedef struct user_t{
    char user_name[30];
    char email[50];
    int movieswatched;
    movie movielist[];  // The flexible array member,
                        // must always be last and declared as an array without a size
}user_t;
```

A structure like this must be allocated dynamically (with e.g. `malloc`), for example as

```
user_t *my_user = malloc(sizeof *my_user + sizeof(movie) * 50);  // Allocate space for 50 movies
```

Comment: Very nice indeed. Didn't know about this!

Comment: This is a 'new' feature.  That is, I believe it was introduced in C99, so is only ~20 years old ;)

Comment: That said, the combined allocation is pretty idiomatic, but the flexible array member removes the need to then do the pointer manipulation by hand afterwards.

Comment: @EddInglis And the "struct hack" that flexible array members standardized was the idiomatic approach for probably 20 years prior to that, so the concept is pretty much as old as C itself.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I didn't know that, cheers.  Here is a random linky that explains it for the curious: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/struct-hack/

Answer (score 2):

You could define a 'factory' function.  That's a fancy name for a function that does both mallocs for you.  Something like :

```
user_t *user_factory( const int movies_watched )
{
    user_t *user = malloc(sizeof *my_user);  // should check for NULL

    user->movieswatched = movies_watched;
    user->movielist = malloc(sizeof(movie) * movies_watched);

    return user;
}
```

It's common to combine the mallocs, BTW, then you can use @someprogrammerdude's flexible array member approach (but still wrap it in the factory).  The other advantage of their way is that it's harder to have an accidental memory leak.

If you really want an automatic variable as you have in your example, then you can have a half-way house of `init` (and `deinit`) functions:

```
void init_user_t( user_t *user, const int movies_watched )
{
    user->movieswatched = movies_watched;
    user->movielist = malloc(sizeof(movie) * movies_watched);
}

void deinit_user_t( user_t *user )
{
    free( user->movielist );
    user->movielist = NULL;
    user->movieswatched = 0;
}

...

user_t my_user;
init_user_t( &my_user, 6 /*num_movies*/ );
```